# How can I get hg diff to show me lines that have been moddifed or added, but not lines that have been deleted?

Tags: mercurial, diff

I want to use a Python script to do some processing on all the lines of code that have been modified or added in a specific commit. Right now I'm using

> hg diff -r .^ -U0

to generate all the differences from this change. But this also shows lines that were removed. Since these lines don't exist after the commit, I don't want to process them.

How do I tell hg diff to generate a diff that only shows lines that were modified or added?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell hg diff to generate a diff

Nohow. Diff is diff and reflect **all** changes in source. But you script can (easy) ignore deleted lines in diffs